# Determine if the sequence $\sqrt{1/(n^2 +1)}$ converges or diverges, before calculating the limit

Tags: calculus

Does anybody know how to determine convergence or divergence with definitions?
I should use such definitions:
For any ε > 0 there exists some n ∈ N such that 1/n < ε.

Comment: What have you tried to solve this problem?

Comment: I've tried using this definition:
For any ε > 0 there exists some n ∈ N such that 1/n < ε.
But still don't know how

Comment: It is a good habit to write that in the question. This way you have more chances to get an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can show that this sequence converges to $0$. Given $\epsilon >0$ you only need to take any $n_0 > 1/\epsilon$. This way, for $n>n_0$ you have
$$
\begin{array}{c}
n>1/\epsilon\\
n^2>1/\epsilon^2>1/\epsilon^2-1\\
n^2+1>1/\epsilon^2\\
\sqrt{n^2+1}>1/\epsilon\\
\end{array}
$$
and finally
$$
\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}<\epsilon
$$

So the sequence converge to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean series as in
$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2+1}}$$

In case you mean series, then it definitely diverges
$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2+1}}$$
$$>\sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2+3n^2}}$$
$$=\sqrt{\frac{1}{4n^2}}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2n}$$

and $\frac{1}{n}$ is a known divergent series.

On the other hand, in case you mean the actual sequence, then the sequence itself converges since
$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2+1}}$$
$$<\sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2}}$$
$$=\frac{1}{n}$$

and $\frac{1}{n}$ is a known convergent sequence.